# Run windows 10 ARM on QEMU

Tags: windows, android-emulator, emulators, termux

I have downloaded the Windows 10 ARM on my Android phone, but it stops when I press any keys to boot from the CD or DVD.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

<sup>Click the images for full-size</sup>

This is my `start.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 2
echo "Starting ..."
qemu-system-aarch64 \
  -M virt \
  -cpu cortex-a57 \
  -smp 6 \
  -m 1G \
  -pflash QEMU_EFI.img \
  -pflash QEMU_VARS.img \
  -device VGA \
  -device nec-usb-xhci \
  -device usb-kbd \
  -device usb-mouse \
  -device usb-storage,drive=install \
  -drive if=none,id=install,format=raw,media=cdrom,file=arm.ISO \
  -device usb-storage,drive=drivers \
  -drive if=none,id=drivers,readonly=on,file=drivers.vhdx \
  -device virtio-blk,drive=system \
  -drive if=none,id=system,format=raw,file=Hard.qcow2 \
  -vnc 127.0.0.1:2
```

And there it stops working. What can I do to make it go off successfully?

Answer (score 2):

I think you must compile `qemu-system=aarch64` by yourself, but go into the `/arm` folder of the source code. You have to go in the file `virt.c` and modify line `has_el3=false` to `has_el3=true`.

Microsoft Windows wants a trust zone, so we emulate it. It will compile, though it will have no GUI, and you have to start this from the command line back on Android, and then vnc into it.

The OS seems still experimental though.